# Cannot see ttf font (converted from otf) in DOS properties/fonts list

Tags: windows-10, command-line, fonts

`using Win10;`

I downloaded a `TTF` font ([this one](http://sensi.org/~svo/glasstty/)), installed it and selected it to use as DOS font (properties - fonts). This worked, but the non-breaking space displays a strange character:

[image]

So I imported the font into `Glyphr`, found the character, replaced by an empty one (removed the shapes), saved the font as `otf` (not possible to export as `ttf`) and converted to `ttf` (tried 2 different online tools). I can install the resulting `ttf` font and use it in Word or Outlook. However, it does not even appear in the list of `ttf` fonts available for DOS.

I also tried adding it manually in the registry (something like `NT-Console-TrueTypeFonts`) and fonts folder, but no luck.

**Questions**

1. Why does the converted font not appear in the TTF font list for DOS?
2. Is it possible to use OTF fonts in DOS command prompt?

Comment: Not sure about why it does not work, but one solution (/workaround) is to use a TTF editor like http://fontstore.baidu.com/static/editor/index-en.html to edit the TTF font directly.

Comment: The fonts used in the Command Prompt, must be monospaced fonts. In addition to the monospaced criteria, Microsoft also specifies that the font for the Command Prompt must satisfy more [esoteric requirements](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-add-fonts-to-the-command-prompt/). However, if your `Glyphr` can save the font as [raster font](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/gdi/raster--vector--truetype--and-opentype-fonts?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (`fon` extension) then try adding it to `"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\RasterFonts"`.